# Event time displaying in GMT after clicking "more details"

Tags: events, calendar, google-calendar-api, gmt

My default Google Calendar timezone is "(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time". The event time displays correctly on the calendar and in the initial pop-up window, but if a viewer who is NOT logged in to Google Calendar clicks the "more details>>" link in the pop-up window, the next screen displays the time in "GMT (no daylight saving)". So, for example, an event that displayed as "8:45am Eastern" on the calendar and in the pop-up now displays as "12:45pm GMT (no daylight saving)" on this "more details" page. Could you please let me know to resolve this.

Comment: Wait, how can someone see the calendar events if s/he is not logged in?

Comment: If the event is public, then anyone can view the event without the need to login.

Comment: Yes, but not without logging into your gmail account. Can you share an example here?

Comment: Assume I had set the start time of an event named "party" to 12 AM (GMT-05:00) EST, In my website if I click on the event name "party", It will redirect to a page where the event details is displayed. If a user is logged in to his gmail, then the event start time is shown as 12 AM. If a user is logged out from his gmail account, the event's start time is shown as 5 AM. ie., 5 hours ahead of the EST. Could you please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple fix for this issue and it is that we need to append &ctz=America/Chicago to #URL# and now logged-out users see the correct timezone.